# SQL select statement that shows non-existant column?

Tags: sql, select

If I have a application that accepts a query that returns 4 columns, 1 of which is an extra info column that can be empty, and the column doesn't exist in the database I am using how could I 'create' it so that the data retrieved using the query always has 4 columns, 1 nbeing empty?

Comment: it might be helpful to add the database you are using...

Comment: There are two :) SQL Server and Oracle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
select c1, c2, c3, null as c4 from table;
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work in Oracle, haven't tried in anything else:

```
select null thiscolumnisempty, id,id2,id3 from table
```

Comment: That will work in Sybase, and probably MySQL as well, it's fairly standard.

Answer (score 1):

select c1, c2, c3, '' as c4 from table;
select c1, c2, c3, 0 as c4 from table;
if you want int then take 0 or if you want varchar then take ''.

Answer (score -1):

You can have 3 fields in database table, but return 4 columns in your sql SELECT script:

```
SELECT id, column2, column3, id FROM YourTable;
```

So you'll get 4 columns return but 3 real columns in db table.